# distro update - something went wrong with apache

Tags: apache2, 22.04

few days ago I started a distro upgrade from Ubuntu 20.04 to 22.04. Something did not go properly (possible an human error :( ).

Initially the repo file was wrong (jammy insted focal) with partial new installation. I changed the repo file and manage to 'downgrade' the system

After this I upgrade the distro again which went I would say not too bad until the end when I realized issues with the apache server. Reading the journalctl errors I realized apache was serching for php7.4 that seams installed but it wasn't. I update the repo file as adequate for php and installed php7.4

Now I still have problem on all web application installed.
I checked the Apache service status and it is green. In the passenger watchdog and passenger core there is a long list of "".

```
             ├─2968 "Passenger watchdog" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" ""
             ├─2971 "Passenger core" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" ""
```

I cheched the apache error log and the only and these are the entries after rebooting the server:

```
[Thu Dec 29 00:20:48.390727 2022] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 2965] AH00163: Apache/2.4.54 (Ubuntu) SVN/1.14.1 mod_fcgid/2.3.9 Phusion_Passenger/6.0.6 OpenSSL/3.0.2 mod_perl/2.0.12 Perl/v5.34.0 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Thu Dec 29 00:20:48.391005 2022] [core:notice] [pid 2965] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
[ E 2022-12-29 00:20:50.7466 2971/T5 age/Cor/SecurityUpdateChecker.h:521 ]: A security update is available for your version (6.0.6) of Phusion Passenger. We strongly recommend upgrading to version 6.0.14.
[ E 2022-12-29 00:20:50.7468 2971/T5 age/Cor/SecurityUpdateChecker.h:526 ]: Additional security update check information:
- [Fixed in 6.0.14] [CVE-2018-25032] zlib before 1.2.12 allows memory corruption when deflating (i.e., when compressing) if the input has many distant matches.
- [Fixed in 6.0.14] A use after free memory safety issue was introduced in 6.0.12, and fixed in 6.0.14.
```

In the phusion passenger there is no info about any ubuntu version after 18.04

Bottom line: the couple of web application installed have basic configuration or let say I did not change much from standard apache2/php settings and I'm wondering if a fresh apache installation after purging the actual one won't be quicker then find the error.

I'm open to follow suggestion how to investigate the error.

Thanks

Comment: I suggest you fresh install Ubuntu 22.04

Comment: Ubuntu 22.04 uses PHP 8. Are you using a version of 7.4 from the Ondrej PPA? Depending on the age of your codebase for the website, you may want to first confirm that the code will work in PHP 8 as there are a number of changes that completely remove some long-deprecated functions from 4.x and 5.x.

Answer (score 0):

after spending several hours on local logs and forums, before reaching the last decision about new installation, I went over all issues again checking repository file and sources. I believe that with Apache, as I have confirmed existing conf file during the distro upgrade, anything like php, passenger, ruby were not up to date or some configuration file become corrupted.

When apache status become "green" then I understood I was going in the right direction and the problem was not the web server itself but all modules and/or configurations

It is a lenghty process but at least I'm glad it is working

I hope this will help someone